# Pop up warning message

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to have a nice pop up warning that says "Are you sure you want to overwrite this file? Yes  No.  Is there any way to do this with telerik or Ajax Tool Kit?. I want to be able to control it on the server side too with c#

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to control at server side ? as you have ajax toolkit,can't you use javascript 'confirm' and pass the control to server side via ajax ?

Comment: What do you mean, control it server-side?  The page will run on the client, which aspect do you want to control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way could be

1) create a div like a popup

2) display the popup when some events occurs (like button click)

3) if users click ok then doing somethings on server side

4) if users click no then hide the div

Here some code, sorry if there is some error but i don't have the environment on my hands.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showConfirm()
{
   var popup = document.getElementbyId('popup');
   popup.style.display = '';
}
function hide()
{
   var popup = document.getElementbyId('popup');
   popup.style.display = 'none';

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server" id="form1">
  <div id="popup" style="display:none">
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
    <asp:button id="btn_ok" runat="server" OnClick="ServerRountine_Click"/>
    <asp:button id="btn_ko" runat="server" onclientclick="hide();"/>
  </div>

<asp:button id="btn_overwrite" runat="server" onclientclick="showConfirm();"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
jConfirm(message, [title, callback])
```

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Comment: Whats the point in going for jquery as op is using telerik and it has confirm box too

Answer (score 0):

You can put an OnClick (or OnClientClick if it's a serverside control) event on your submit button like the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit new file" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to overwrite this file?')) return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prolly use asp modalpopup for this ;p
... but yeah you want to do it with ajax etc.
I think you'd love jq-ui then.

It is almost the same as above , but it will style the popup at the same time;p

```
  $("#modEdit").dialog({//modEdit is your Div with any controls.
                autoOpen: false,//Properties
                width: 600,
                show: "fade",
                hide: "fade",
                modal: true,
                buttons: {//Buttons
                    "Save Changes": function () {
                        ModSaveChanges();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Syntax  looks in short like this $(control).dialog({properties,buttons:{btn1,btn2}}); etc

really easy, I really recomend it ^^ :D
I have used it for my Mobile Apps;p
Oh and you might also then take a look into Sencha Ext ;p